# Using a shell variable within Makefile

Tags: gnu-make

I have a line line in make file for compiling a c program, which goes like this 
`$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)`. I have to modify a particular line in code every time and compile again. Modification  is just an argument to a function. I have the argument in one file and i use `sed` utility to modify my c source and then compile. I want to see which of the arguements leads to successful compilation. I tried to use this `$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) ; echo $? >status` where I was hoping if compilation was successful `status` file would have an entry `0`. But i see the source file name in `status` file. I came to know that `$?` is also a make automatic variable. How can i read the shell variable `$?` within makefile ?  I have tried using `$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) ; echo $$? >status` and `$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) ; echo $(shell echo $?) >status` without getting correct results.

Comment: Escaping the `$` is right (using `echo $$? > status`).  What do you mean by "without getting correct results"?  What results do you get?

Comment: Are you using a Unix-like operating system? Because on Windows `$?` is called `%errorlevel%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version

```
echo $$? > status
```

definitely works for me. What OS are you using? What are the incorrect results when using `$$?`?

If you are on Windows, there is no `$?`, you might want ot use `%errorlevel%` instead.

Comment: Some how  `echo $$?` seems to work now. I am sure i have tried this, and i was getting the source file name in `status`. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @MadScientist escaping with `$` is working now, I had tried it earlier and I was getting source file name in `status` file. It seems I was doing some thing wrong before.